# Setting up a UITableView with page cells and autoresizes its cell by autorotation of device

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit, paging, autorotate

(SOLUTION NOTE, NOT A QUESTION, I'LL ANSWER IMMEDIATELY)

When an `UITableViewController` is automatically rotating, its `UITableView` is resized automatically, but its cells are not resized and even wrongly positioned after rotation.

Especially, in the case of paging, this is worse. You may set `pagingEnabled` to `YES` and height of cells to `[UITableView bounds].size.height` to present paging. However after the `UITableView` auto-rotated, all things are messed.

How can I make those cells resized by table view rotation automatically?

Answer (score 5):

Make a `UITableViewController` like this. Core concept is `beginUpdate` before rotation, and `endUpdate` after rotation. With only these, cell's auto-resizing will be done automatically. However, their positioning will not. So I added a manual scroll to specific position.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [tableView bounds].size.height;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return  YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];  
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];  
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates]; 

    //  We have to specify an position to scroll to explicitly and manually
    //  becase current page number is no determinable especially if user rotate device continually.
    NSIndexPath*    indexPath   =   [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    [[self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self tableView] setPagingEnabled:YES];
}
```